# Phonegap FileTransfer .upload never fires successCallback

Tags: android, cordova, upload, android-camera

I'm trying to submit an image (either taken from camera, or selected from gallery) to my upload server by using cordova file-transfer plugin.
The camera plugin works fine, I can see the image -- taken with camera or selected from gallery -- being displayed on screen (by using <img /> tag).

When trying to implement the FileTransfer.Upload, [the docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md) states that the upload method has some arguments, including success/error callback functions.
This is my portion of code:

```
function uploadPhoto() {
    var imageURI = document.getElementById('ImageSource').getAttribute("src");
    if (!imageURI) {
        alert('Please select an image first.');
        return;
    }
    console.log("imageURI = " + imageURI);

    var url=encodeURI("http://my.server.path/upload.php");
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.mimeType = "multipart/form-data";
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    console.log("Starting Transfer...");

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, url, 
        function (r) {
            alert('Finished upload!');
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert('Error uploading image with code: ' + error.code)
        }, 
        options
     );

     console.log("Finishing Transfer...");
}
```

### The Callbacks are not firing

Running the app on an Android Emulator, I get no alert. I can't tell whether it was a success or a failure. But the strange thing is: **the image file get uploaded to my server, and I can see these two lines delievered on the log:**

```
D/CordovaLog( 2487): file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js: Line 123 : imageURI = content://media/external/images/media/24
D/CordovaLog( 2487): file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js: Line 147 : Starting Transfer...
D/CordovaLog( 2487): file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js: Line 163 : Finishing Transfer...
```

Can somebody kindly point me out, where should I look? Because I can't handle the response. I need to get the server response, and display a processed image back to the screen.

Comment: Are you solved this issue...

Comment: Sorry for not keeping my eye on this one, here. Nope, I never have any solution for that work. Sorry.